# How to set TFS's communications port?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

How can I properly set the port on which the TFS server and services communicate? By default, it's 8080. I've tried to set it to 8081, and it almost works, but when I run a build from VS, I get an error message:

> Exception Message: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 192.168.38.139:8080 (type SocketException)
>   Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)

Comment: What version of TFS?

Comment: I installed TFS 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to un-configure your application tier with the "tfsconfig setup /uninstall:all" command then reconfigure choosing tge "advanced" wizard.

You will be asked what url and port you wish tfs to run on on one of the configuration pages.

Comment: Looks like the right track. But I'm failing at the database part - it's complaining about the existing database. I tried giving another label, complained about the DefaultCollection. Wish I could just delete that first database, but I don't see a SQL Server utility to do that.

Comment: I tried the Application-Tier only wizard and that let me complete the reconfiguration. But I get the same result when I run the job. I wonder how much I need to nuke in order to get things to work. I'll try creating a new team project.